# Getting UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 0, signal null error in android version above 10 in redmi

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Im getting below error in devices which is having more than 10 android versions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO2oV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install the appium again. And use some other companies manufacturing device with android version 11.